# MOSFET cascode current

Tags: transistors, mosfet, cascode

I have the following circuit:

[image]

I have two questions:

- Is it possible to implement this circuit with non-matched MOSFET transistors?
- How can I calculate the resistance to connect both in I_in and I_out?

Thanks

Comment: Transistors are never perfectly matched, so in some sense you must always use "non-matched" transistors. What do you really mean by "implement this circuit"?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. So if I am not mistaken in order to have this circuit working as a Current Source I need M1 and M2 matched and M3 and M4 matched. I have made my analysis based on those asumptions.

Comment: To the extent that the transistors are not matched, the output current will not match the input current, in most cases. As MOSFET's are not linear, unmatched devices may cause the output to not even be linear in relation to the input. Is there a reason why you might want to use devices that are relatively unmatched?

Comment: Hello, unfortunately I have some BS170 transistors and I don't count on IC with matched transistors

Comment: Please separate your two questions as they are unrelated. One of the objectives of the site is to provide useful re-useable answers to benefit everyone. This gets lost when multiple questions are asked in a single posting.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this with non-matched MOSFETs it just won't perform as well. You should at least try to pair M1 and M2, and M3 and M4 i.e. choose the same part for each of these two pairs. BTW the same part is NOT matching as there will be some degree of variation in certain characteristics for the same part number e.g. IDSS. In some cases you can manually measure these characteristic and "find" a pair.

Devices with a closer match can be found on ICs that have multiple MOSFETs. These will be manufactured the same and experience the same environment e.g. temperature considerations as they are on the same die. Look at diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds31757.pdf for an example.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Me last query is which is the V_in minimum and V_out minimum that I should use:

Per my analysis (thinking as all transistors as equivalents) is that for Vin min I'd need 2Vgs-2Vth and for Vout min I'd need 2Vgs - Vth. Am I right?